# How to make a plugin for Adobe reader in Windows?

Tags: c++, .net, wpf, plugins, adobe-reader

I just want to know how to make a plugin for Adobe reader and how does it works, I have Stuided the SDK Documenty on Adobe plugin, but even i can understand how to add a button in to adobe reader using c++ and when clicked I want to run a Function which i have make in WPF c#, How to do that... Please Help me .,.,

Comment: show some code how and what you've tried so far.

Comment: @pushpraj Is it possible to write any plugin to Adobe Reader using C#? I can't find any info about it.